# Drupal 7 - multi language mixed menu

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, multilingual

is it possible to create a mixed English/Italian items menu? 
I must create an Italian section on an English website.

I have created a link on the main menu to access to the Italian section (link4). All the others links are neutral or English:

Menu:

- link1(neutral)
- link2(en)
- link3(en)
- link4(it)

  - link5(it)

The language detection is currently URL based (*abc.it/**it*** for Italian and *abc.it* for English). 
When I click on *link4* or *link5*, I see the Italian pages correctly. Then if I click on *link1*, *2* or *3*, the website remain in Italian and the URL changes in abc.it/**it**/link1 and obviously doesn't find the node (that is *abc.it/link1*).

How can I solve this?
Should I use a domain detection?
Should I disable the double languages and use a neutral language for all contents?
Keep in mind that the Italian section has 2 kinds of content: translations from the English and new contents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and never managed to figure out a way to get it to work 'automagically'. So I basically duplicated the menu for each language (in my case English and Dutch). For sake of simplicity, assume that all nodes > 10 are translations of the nodes < 10, so node 11 is the translation of node 1.

So my main menu looks something like this:

- Home (en) -> node/1

  - News (en) -> node/2
  - About us (en) -> node/3
  - Some topic (en) -> node/4
- Start (nl) -> node/11

  - Nieuws (nl) -> node/12
  - Over ons (nl) -> node/13
  - Onderwerp (nl) -> node/14

Note that I **always** have the language in the url: mydomain.nl/en/some-url and mydomain.nl/nl/translated-url

When the visitor switches language, the menu switches too.

Comment: I did the same for another website, but I don't need to translate the English links. That is the problem. Basically I don't need the language detection.

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry I can't provide any help. I can only confirm your findings: there is no 'automagic' change of language.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to have a mixed menu is to disable translations and create individual content for each language.